# SAGA-GIS:Viewshed creation from SHP instead of interactively?

Tags: saga, viewshed

I am using SAGA-GIS to calculate a viewshed from a single point. I can do this with the interactive module, (terrain analysis > Lighting > visibility (single point) interactive)  but how do I do it from a shapefile? Any tips?

Comment: Also...any infos regarding the settings for the viewshed (Shade, distance, height) would be most welcome)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly you can't do this in SAGA. I recommend you GRASS. You have a module named [r.cva](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_AddOns#r.cva).

Answer (score 0):

SAGA 2.1.0 can perform viewshed analysis for multiple points. You can vectorize it by following method.
Modules > Shapes >Grid >Vectorization..

Thnks